# Xpath seem to be right when i use chrome but fails on selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to find the text box in the image below

[image]

My xpath using chrome is

```
div[@id='element.problem.short_description']
div[@class='col-xs-10 col-md-9 col-lg-8 form-field input_controls']
```

still it fails on selenium.

the code is here on the webpage. I Couldn't copy it for some reason, so attaching a screenshot of it

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: try css selector: `div#element.problem.short_description  .input_controls  input#problem.short_description`  or `input#problem.short_description`

Comment: When it fails, how it fails, do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Always test your locators in the browser. `$$()` can be used to test CSS selectors and `$x()` can be used to test XPath. Make sure it returns what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not looking at the text field.

All you need is `//input[@id='problem.short_description']`